# Windows Can't Find SepSysPlant.exe?

Tags: windows-xp, sp3, symantec

In the last two days I've suddenly started receiving the following error message:
"Windows cannot find'C:\WINDOWS\sepsysplant.exe'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and try again.To Search for a file, click the start."

It comes and goes with no apparent association with any running applications. I only have a bare minimum of programs installed as this is a work machine (XP Pro SP3) and the Symantec virus scan (today's definitions) were unable to find anything.

After a quick Google search I found 4 results all of which were asking the question or stating the existence of the file and the Yahoo search resulted with nothing.

Anyone know what's causing this a way of tracking down what it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sepsysplant is a part of the Symantec Endpoint Security. Most probably you've got it installed wrong. Just reinstall the Symantec AV, that should do the work.

Comment: Thanks. I just upgraded the software and the issue went away. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: This error started happening to me one day after an update.

Answer (score 1):

Start with **[Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx)**. It will list everything that is automatically started on system boot, login, and so on.

**[Rootkit Revealer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897445.aspx)** is worth trying too.

If the error message appears constantly, the cause might be logged by **[ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)**.

Finally, **[Microsoft Security Essentials](http://www.microsoft.com/security_essentials/)** might be a better antivirus than Symantec. (I completely lost trust in Norton and Symantec security software several years ago. Besides, what's better at fixing Windows than Micros~1 own products?)